# What is the word for a magnificent history?

Tags: single-word-requests

As I asked in the title, I always use Chinese Youdao dictionary to check some English words, and again this time I forgot the word, it's just a single word, and it means(perhaps it can be **Figuratively** used as) a great period of history and the Chinese translation given was *波澜壮阔的历史画卷(literally means a canvas of splendid & marvellous history)*，or something like that but I'm not gonna type that many Chinese in as I think that doesn't make sense here.

Can anyone give me some hints?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101135/discussion-on-question-by-angyang-what-is-the-word-for-a-magnificent-history).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP commented that they remembered the requested word, namely "pageant".

Answer (score 2):

> **Golden age**
>
> *noun*
>
> 1) the most flourishing period in the history of a nation, literature, etc.
>
> [Source: Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/golden-age)

Comment: yeh something like this but it was a word I HOPE.. if my memory was right, and it was used metaphorically

Comment: **Golden age** _is_ a metaphor.

Answer (score 2):

Epoch may  be  the  word you  are looking  for.

> Epoch  means:    A long  period  in which  new  and  great  developments  take  place.

For example  we  say:

> The development  of  steam  engine  marked  an  epoch  in the  history  of  Industry.
>
> The  rule  of  the  Gupta  Dynasty  is  considered  an  epoch  in  Indian History.

In view  of the  above examples  I think  *epoch*  is  the  suitable  word  in  the  context.

Here is the  link.

.             https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/epoch

Comment: Since I have  given  examples  using  epoch, I hope  the  above  comment  is  deleted

Answer (score 0):

> **Renaissance**
>   [ ren-uh-sahns, -zahns, -sahns, ren-uh-sahns, -zahns, -sahns; especially British ri-ney-suhns ]
>
> *noun*
>
> 3) (sometimes lowercase) any similar revival in the world of art and learning.
>
> 4) (lowercase) a renewal of life, vigor, interest, etc.; rebirth; revival.
>
> [Source: Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/renaissance)

Answer (score -1):

> **epic**[ ep-ik ]
>
> adjective Also ep·i·cal.
>
> 1) noting or pertaining to a long poetic composition, usually centered upon a hero, in which a series of great achievements or events is narrated in elevated style:
>   Homer's Iliad is an epic poem.
>
> 2) resembling or suggesting such poetry:
>   an epic novel on the founding of the country.
>
> 3) heroic; majestic; impressively great.
>
> [Source: Dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/epic)